# nodejs/curl http request is slow compared to postman rest client

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, postman

I call a Rest API from node.js and Postman-Rest Client (chrome app).
Always using the same computer, same endpoint and same parameters.

In node.js I get ~400ms for http and ~700ms for https.
In Postman I get ~250ms for http and https.

Libraries I used in node.js: http, https, request, kinvey (node client of the api). All of them got the the same result more or less.

Why my node is slower?

node.js 0.10.36

Edit:
it's not about node, i get the same result with curl.
when running in browser using XMLHttpRequest i get better times.
from analysing the logs I found that TCP connect and SSL handshake takes about 500ms. It may be that TCP connect and SSL handshake works differently in browser.

Comment: Did you try disabling the use of the Http Agent?

Comment: startup time? Try to measure first request time, then (from success callback) start and measure another request

Comment: @AndreySidorov I ran about 5-10 requests and the 400/700ms is an average time, I even excluded the first time connections.

Comment: @mscdex Yes I tried, got same results

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find some help.
I am also facing issues with nodejs application server on linux instance. But dont blame nodejs as real issue is in linux systems.

**Issue** : any outbound request from machine need to find the domain , hence it always lookup the DNS entries & always handshakes with secure/unsecure protocols. This is actually the time taking scenario.
You can verify by doing CURL request.

`curl --trace-time -v https://outboundserver.com`

**Solution** : We have to White List IP of outbound server in our own DNS entries. take a look below ...

**IN Windows** : automatically does the mapping of servers in own dns entries.

**IN Linux** : We have to manually add the hosts corresponding to IP Address. 
Manually add an entry in /etc/hosts file below any configuration like localhost.

`127.0.0.1     localhost
outbound.servers.ip.address www.outboundserver.com`

Finally check with the curl request again, it should give faster response.

`curl --trace-time -v https://outboundserver.com`